# Variables in templates don't use the language key

Tags: 7, i18n-l10n

I have a multilingual website using Drupal 7. I installed the i18n modules (entity translation, etc). In templates, I use variables like `$vars['und']`.

I think Drupal ran updates. Now the template system uses `$var` without the language as key. I think I activated block translation.
Templates still work for anonymous users, but they don't work for the administrator user.

Do you know what happened?

Answer (score 1):

Once you are logged in, another language is requested and the 'und' key no longer works:
https://www.deeson.co.uk/labs/programatically-access-field-data-using-entitymetadatawrapper-drupal
Try replacing your use of $vars['und'][0]['value'] with Entity metadata wrappers. More examples here: https://www.drupal.org/documentation/entity-metadata-wrappers

Comment: You are right. I think that field_get_items will also work in this situation.